# Small Question on Relative Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

Let $(X,Y)$ be a pair of topological spaces.

How can we prove that the boundary map $\partial: C_p(X)\rightarrow C_{p-1}(X)$ sends $C_p(Y)$ to $C_{p-1}(Y)$>

If I take a singular p-simplex of $Y$ then why is its boundary on $C_{p-1}(Y)$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the boundary map?

Comment: yes,but if $\partial: C_p(X)\rightarrow C_{P-1}(X)$ and $\sigma \in C_p(Y)$ we are sure that $\partial\sigma$ is on $C_{p-1}(X)$ but why precisely on $C_{p-1}(Y)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\sigma \in C_p(Y)$ be a basis element. This means that $\sigma$ is a map $\Delta^p \to Y$. By definition we have
$$
\partial \sigma = \sum_i (-1)^i \sigma\mid[v_0, \ldots, \widehat v_i, \ldots, v_n].
$$

Each element $\sigma\mid[v_0, \ldots, \widehat v_i, \ldots, v_n]$ is a restriction of $\sigma$ to $\Delta^{p-1}$, hence a map $\Delta^{p-1} \to Y$. It follows that $\partial \sigma \in C_{p-1}(Y)$.

The general result follows by linearity of $\partial$.

Comment: Elements of $C_p(Y)$ are linear combinations of singular simplices, your calculation is valid for the generating set containing all singular $p$-simplices though. Maybe edit your answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: @ChristophPegel Yes, the calculation generalizes to linear combinations by the linearity of $\partial$. I think this is obvious and this is why it's implicit in my answer. Edited to avoid any confusion anyway.